# Split a single Angular Controller into multiple JS files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js

am trying to create an application with Angularjs for our financial client. They need the whole application in one single page. I am convincing them to use tabs at least. But the actual problem is the application has almost 2000 fields and half of them are calculated based on the input and some numbers from the database.

I have segregated the application using few controllers. But still each controller will be humongous given all the calculations.

1. Is there a way to split a single Controller into multiple JS files?
2. We have developed similar application for the same client using KnockoutJS. Which was fairly easy with observables and Computed features from KO. Or is it a better idea to stay with KO ? Imagining doing all the calculation across Controllers seems to be very difficult.

Please suggest.

Comment: I've never worked with Angular, but if you enjoyed Knockout and it fits your architecture, maybe check out [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/)

Comment: It's not really clear what you exactly need, but maybe you can separate some logic using services and factories for the calculations, with reusability benefits

Comment: I agree with Daniele, you can use also Directives to have reusable code like calculations.

Comment: @Mark I am marreid to Angular now, so it's too late for me, but Durandal does look good http://durandaljs.com/showcase.html  Others might want to check it out

Answer (score 4):

Angular isn't bad by design, but it is prone to be misused. The fact that Angular doesn't suggest anything for models or inheritance (you're on your own with JS prototypes, and POJO, and `extend` or`copy` for mixins) doesn't help at all.

If you have the background with modern MVC frameworks in OOP languages, you're probably familiar with 'thin controllers, fat models' conception. In Angular case it is 'thin controllers, fat services' (it isn't MVC but MVW framework after all).

If you're about to detach some functions into separate object (file?), then it is ready-to-go [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) (most likely `factory`). Think of Angular services as of usual objects (models, utility classes, asynchronous services, whatever) that fit DI pattern.

It is quite amusing to see how Angular good practices developed in the last couple of years. One of them is using the controller for the sole thing where they shine - getting the data from services and putting it into scope, and using `$scope.$...` functions, it helps to avoid [scope soup](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html).

Another [recent conception](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html) (influenced by web components) I'm fond of is replacing controllers (`ng-controller` is itself a directive, which offers you nothing but controller, hence the name) with directives. The latter may provide higher level of encapsulation (via isolate scope) and controller interoperation (with `require`).

It have taken some time for me to figure it out, but if you have to struggle with Angular, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: " if you have to struggle with Angular, you're probably doing something wrong"" ??  http://www.bennadel.com/resources/uploads/2013/feelings_about_angularjs_over_time.png  :-)

Comment: @Mawg Very true. Actually, this applies to any overengineered framework.

Comment: Glad you saw the humo(u)r :-)   I will be following your advice and moving lots of controller code into services (+1)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is *no*. Your controller must be defined as a single function.

However you should break the logic in the controller into separate services. In fact the controller should have *very* little logic in it. All data you need to share with other controllers and directive should be stored within the services you create. Separate directives and controllers would use the services to update the get the values they need.

Also note that if you have anything in the controller that is manipulating the DOM all of that logic should be in a directive.